# Difference between llvm-as and binutils-as, naming of variables

Tags: gcc, llvm, gnu-assembler, binutils

I try to assemble an example

test.s:

```
        .file   "test.c"
        .text
        .globl  f
        .type   f, @function
f:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        movl    $"A,B", %eax
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   f, .-f
        .comm   "A,B",4,4
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 7.3.0"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

```
$ binutils-2.35/bin/as test.s
test.x86.s: Assembler messages:
test.x86.s:8: Warning: missing closing '"'
test.x86.s:8: Warning: missing closing '"'
test.x86.s:8: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
```

```
$ clang-9 -c test.s ; echo $?
0
```

Why clang-9 can assembly test and gnu-as can't do it?

P.S. Basically, test was created from python/numba/llvmlite llvm-IR (as result of llvm's optimizations?).

Comment: It may be a bug, as GNU as [says](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Intro.html#Symbol-Intro) that any character except NUL is allowed in a symbol name if enclosed by quotes.

Comment: If it is a bug, so how it is possible to submit a bug or to ask a llvm's developers to submit a bug (because https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla : "User account creation has been restricted")?